# Django RequestFactory doesn't store a User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm testing whether an API User can `POST` to a view if the User can pass the `IsAuthenticated` permission. Upon running the test I get the assertion error: `AssertionError: 401 != 201`.

When `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)` is commented out and the test is ran again, I'm finding that `request.user` is turning out to be an `AnonymousUser`. Yet, I have a `User` created and attached to the request as shown below.

I'm not sure what is causing this, and looking to understand how I can pass a User instance to the request.

*Note* - I'm trying to do this in the Django testing API rather than use Django REST Framework.

**tests.py**

```
class TestUserPreferencesResource(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a User is capable of setting preferences for their profile'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        cls.user = User.objects.create_user('Mock', password="secret")

        cls.user_prefs = json.dumps({
            "age": ['Baby', 'Adult'],
            "gender": ['Male'],
            "size": ["Medium", "Large"]
        })

        cls.factory = RequestFactory()
        cls.credentials = b64encode(b"Mock:secret").decode("ascii")


    def test_user_preferences_settings(self):
        request = self.factory.post(
            reverse("pref-settings"),
            data=self.user_prefs,
            content_type="application/json",
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Basic {self.credentials}"
            },
        )
        request.user = self.user
        print(request.user)
        response = UserPrefView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPrefView(
        CreateModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        GenericAPIView):

    queryset = UserPref.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serilaizer_class = serializers.UserPreferenceSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Which authentication class are you using?

Comment: @Ken4scholars - I'm using `[TokenAuthorization, BasicAuthorization]` for the Authentication classes.

Comment: You have an authentication failure. I suspect you are incorrectly encoding the credentials.  Check the response message `response.data`. It should contain a detail of why the authentication failed.